# Automatically switch between German and English spell checking

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, spell-checking

I type 70% in German language and 30% in English language.

I want my webbrowser (and maybe other applications like thunderbird) to automatically switch between both languages when spell checking the things I type.

Of course this includes some type of guessing, but I think it it not hard to automatically detect if a text is in German or English.

Up to now I use firefox. But I am willing to change, if an other web browser supports this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Firefox plugin that does the job:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/automatic-spelling-language/?src=search
I guess you'll need to have both German and English dictionaries installed, of course!

Comment: This didn't work for me. Did it for you @guettli ?